# Solving 4 Quadratic Simultaneous Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider the equations:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> ab+c+d=3\\
> bc+d+a=5\\
> cd+a+b=2\\
> da+c+b=6
> \end{cases}$$
>   Where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. How can we find $a,b,c,d$?

The furthest I've got is by adding the first two equations and the last two equations together to get:
$ab+bc+c+d+d+a=(b+1)(a+c)+2d=8$ and $(d+1)(a+c)+2b=8$
We can rearrange these (assuming $b,d \neq -1$) to get $$\frac{8-2d}{b+1}=\frac{8-2b}{d+1} \implies -d^{2}+3d+4=-b^{2}+3b+4$$
Which leads us further to
$$b^{2}-d^{2}-3(b-d)=0 \implies (b-d)(b+d-3)=0$$
Now since $b=d$ gives us an absurdity (equations 1 and 4 reduce to 3=6), we must have $b+d=3$. This is as far as I can get unfortunately, since trying the same approach with the other pairs doesn't work in the same way.

Help would be much appreciated; the problem is from the BMO1 2004 paper.

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit improving the title and adding two tags, but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1993791).

Comment: @Later Yes, it was me who rejected it. I assume you saw the reason? Adding block elements to the title outweighed the rest of the edit IMO.

Comment: I never add a *block* element to a title. Any math formula enclosed by **single** `$` is considered as an *inline* element.

Comment: @Later 4 lines of equations is a block element, whether it's in inline mode or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $\#1 - \#2 + \#3 - \#4$ to get $(b-d)(a-c)=-6$

$\#1 + \#2 - \#3 - \#4$ gives $(b-d)(a+c-2) = 0$

$\#1 - \#2 - \#3 + \#4$ gives $(b+d-2)(a-c)=2$.

So now $a+c-2 = 0$, and $$\frac{1}{a-c} = \frac{b-d}{-6} = \frac{b+d-2}{2}$$

That gives us $d=3-2b$ and $a-c = \dfrac{-2}{b-1}$ (in particular, $b \ne 1$).
Together with $a+c-2=0$ we get
$a = \dfrac{b-2}{b-1}$, $c = \dfrac{b}{b-1}$.  Finally, substitute into $\#1$ to get
$-b+3=3$, or $b=0$, and thus $a=2$, $c=0$, $d=3$.

Comment: Was there a particular way you found these, or was it obvious to you?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood, I think the trick is that two +'s and two -'s will eliminate all the single variable terms on the LHS. Wish I thought of it!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have a more complicated problem like this, systems of polynomial equations can be best solved with the Dixon Resultant.  If you google that and my name, you will find lots of information.

Robert H. Lewis

Fordham University

Comment: While your suggestion is good for a comment (advice), I am not sure it qualifies for an answer. It would be better to add it as a comment and perhaps provide a link for Dixon Resultant.

Comment: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DixonResultant/